# java on editor action listner

Tags: java, editor, actionlistener

Trying to use on action listner on a edittext using the following

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextnum);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()) ;
```

keep getting error "cannot instantiate the type textview.OnEditorActionListner

any ideas?

mark

UPDATE WORKING CODE HAS ERROR ON TOAST

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextnum);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                EditText mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextnum);
                if(mEdit.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Asset Number Entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    db.open();
                    Cursor c = db.getContact(mEdit.getText());
                    if (c.moveToFirst())        
                        DisplayContact(c);
                    else
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    db.close();
                           }
                }
            return false;
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't implemented the listener.

```
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // do things
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes I did full code is above and gives the error as described. second error is KeyEvent cannot be resolved to a type Any Ideas? Mark

Comment: Please see updated code above it works ok but the two toasts show the error "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){}, String, int)"Any ideas?

Comment: this refer to the inner class .. use YourActivityname.this instead

Comment: thanks guys i got the toast working by swapping this for getBaseContext()